# Upgrading project to Xcode 3.2 under Snow Leopard won't debug

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging

I have an Xcode project that has been upgraded to Xcode 3.2, and whilst it builds fine (and produces an executable that runs fine), when I try to debug it the debugger doesn't start.

When I look in the debugging window, it says that the build was fine.  When I look in the console, I get a 'Session started ', but the application never begins.

I've had a wander through the build settings, and can't see anything that appears to be turned off when it should be turned on.  I thought it may be a new setting that I need to turn on, but I can't see anything of interest that may help.

Any advice would be grateful accepted!

Cheers and thanks.

Comment: I've also got this problem, rebooting or cleaning does not help.  Did you get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a full Clean of the project?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rob for the advice.  I tried rebuilding everything a couple of times and still to no avail.

However, after turning on my machine this morning, trying the project out it now debugs quite happily.  I'm guessing that after installing Xcode I should have rebooted the machine (it didn't require one according to the installer).

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and just discovered that my app launches on the iPhone correctly when I've started Xcode from the finder, but not when I've launched Xcode from my shell.  For example, I start Xcode by typing "open project.xcodeproj" into my bash terminal, and device debugging is broken, but if I start Xcode via spotlight or by double-clicking on my project, or from the Applications folder, device debugging works fine.  I'm not certain, but it appears to be a problem with my shell environment variables.